# What is known about analogous results of Kazdan and Warner in higher dimensions?  

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, chern-classes, riemannian-geometry, geometric-analysis

First let me state a Theorem due to Kazdan and Warner:

``Let M be a compact two dimensional orientable manifold. Let 
$f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function that has the same 
sign as $\chi(M)$, the Euler characteristic of $M$ at some point. 
Then $M$ admits a metric $g$ such that the Gaussian curvature $K$ is 
the given function $f$. ''

(I am actually not sure if orientable is necessary). Is anything 
known about the following question:

``Let M be a compact, orientable manifold. Let 
$f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function that has the same 
sign as $\chi(M)$, the Euler characteristic of $M$ at some point. 
Then does $M$ admit a metric $g$ such that 
$$ *e(TM) = f $$
where $e(TM)$ is the Euler class of the Tangent bundle and 
* is the Hodge star operator?''

Notice that in two dimensions this is precisely the Kazdan Warner 
theorem, since $$*e(TM) = \frac{K}{2 \pi}$$

Comment: Check this Wikipedia page  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prescribed_scalar_curvature_problem

Comment: I am sorry if this is a trivial question or a well known fact, 
but is the Scalar curvature the same as $*e(TM)$ (maybe upto 
a constant factor)? 

Comment: I assume that by $\ast e(TM)$ you mean the Gauss--Bonnet integrand.  In dimensions at least three, it is different from the scalar curvature.  So prescribing scalar curvature is a different question in dimensions at least three.

Comment: @Ritwik, there is no possibility of such an identity holding. If $*e(TM)$ was some multiple of the scalar curvature $R$, this would imply that $\int R = \int *e(TM) dV = <e(TM),[M]>$, and this is a topological invariant of the (smooth structure) topology of $M$. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem#Further_generalizations). However, one can show that in dimensions $\geq 3$, all manifolds admit a metric of negative scalar curvature, e.g. $S^3$. So, if the above identity held, we could evaluate $<e(TM),[M]>$ on the standard metric and this other one...

Comment: ...giving a contradiction. 

You may be interested in the following MO post: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/30035/some-questions-about-scalar-curvature.

Comment: *by my first sentence, I mean an identity between scalar curvature and the Gauss-Bonnet integrand (as @unknown comments)

Comment: Thank you. I see why the scalar curvature can not equal the 
$*e(TM)$. 